# Compare two array objects in deep and store different values in third array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have arrays like this;

```
$scope.result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'pppp', type:'user', username:'345'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

$scope.result2 = [
    {id:1, name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter123', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];
```

I want to compare result2 with result1 .And store only different values in third array.
Expected result is like;

```
$scope.result = [
        { name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123'},
        {name:'Peter123'},
    ];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the same order with same `id` at same index? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: Any of the answers solved your problem? Care to mark an answer or respond at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each object in the second result, you can find out which values differ, and then use those values.

```js
const result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'pppp', type:'user', username:'345'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

const result2 = [
    {id:1, name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter123', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

const getAllKeys = objects => [
  ...(new Set (objects.reduce((prev, curr) => [
    ...prev,
    ...Object.keys(curr)
  ], [])))
];

const getObjectDifferences = (objectOne, objectTwo) => 
  getAllKeys([objectOne, objectTwo])
    .map(key => objectOne[key] !== objectTwo[key] ? key : false)
    .filter(v => !!v)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
      ...prev,
      [curr]: objectTwo[curr],
    }), {})

const getDifferences = (listOne, listTwo) => listTwo
  .map(item => getObjectDifferences(
    listOne.filter(x => x.id === item.id)[0],
    item
  )).filter(item => Object.keys(item).length > 0)
  
console.dir(getDifferences(result1, result2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a map for objects with the same `id` and then check the properties for a change and return only the changed properties in a new array.

```js
var $scope = {
        result1: [{ id:1, name:'pppp', type:'user', username:'345' }, { id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2' }, { id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete' }],
        result2: [{ id:1, name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123' }, { id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2' }, { id:3, name:'Peter123', type:'user', username:'pete' }]
    },
    map = new Map($scope.result1.map(o => [o.id, o]));

$scope.result = $scope.result2.reduce((r, o) => {
    var object = map.get(o.id) || {},
        temp = Object.entries(o).filter(([k, v]) => object[k] !== v);

    if (temp.length) {
        r.push(Object.assign(...temp.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))));
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log($scope.result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If like i think you need to find updated values, you can do it like below:

```
var $scope = {};

$scope.result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'pppp', type:'user', username:'345'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

$scope.result2 = [
    {id:1, name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter123', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

$scope.diffResult = []

for (let i=0; i<$scope.result1.length; i++){
    const o1 = $scope.result1[i];
    const o2 = $scope.result2[i];
    const diff = {};

    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o1).forEach(p => {
        if (o1[p] !== o2[p]) {
            diff[p] = o2[p];
        }
    })

    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(diff).length > 0){
        $scope.diffResult.push(diff);
    }
}

console.log($scope.diffResult);
```

Another possible approach would be to use a more well tested module like deep-diff

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: If there's id:x in result1, there'll be id:x in result2 as well.

First, use map on result2 to determine differences.

Then, use filter on the new array, to weed out empty objects.

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'pppp', type:'user', username:'345'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

var result2 = [
    {id:1, name:'Seema', type:'admin', username:'123'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter123', type:'user', username:'pete'},
];

var result = result2.map(entry2 => {
    var ret = {};
    result1.forEach(entry1 => {
    if (entry2.id === entry1.id){
        if(entry2.name !== entry1.name){
        ret['name'] = entry2.name;
      }
      if (entry2.type !== entry1.type){
        ret['type'] = entry2.type;
      }
      if (entry2.username !== entry1.username){
        ret['username'] = entry2.username;
      }
    }
  });
  return ret;
});

result = result.filter(entry => Object.keys(entry).length > 0);

console.log(result);
```